# Как посмотреть ошибку hibernate getNextException?

Tags: hibernate, java

hibernate иногда валится с ошибкой

> Use getNextException() to retrieve the exceptions for specific batched elements.

Как эту ошибку посмотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас выпало SQLException, то то самое next вы можете увидеть с помощью того самого метода, который /предлагается ииспользовать, а имено [getNextException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getNextException%28%29).

**UPD**

Если HibernateException является [net.sf.hibernate.JDBCException](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-2/api/net/sf/hibernate/JDBCException.html), то у него есть [getSQLException](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-2/api/net/sf/hibernate/JDBCException.html#getSQLException%28%29). В остальных случаях вам скорее всего не удастся получить ссылку на исходный SQLException. Возможно, cause будет указывать на него, но это не обязательно.

Comment: вы вопрос-то поняли?
} catch (HibernateException e) {
//
}

Comment: мне не помог этот ответ/ ошибка org.Hibernate

Comment: Так какого типа исключение падает на самом деле?

Comment: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Comment: Ну так и в чём проблема?? rg.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException extends org.hibernate.JDBCException. А раз так, то у него есть метод getSQLException.